# How to use data in one column in R to create new data in a second column

Tags: r

1.Hello I am currently learning R and  am trying to extract multiple different values from a  single column and assign them to a new tibble/variable

```
postcode|average download speed|  
cv1 4b7           1.3

b16 6yt           1.5
```

2.with this data i want to be able to create a variable which allows me to combine the first 3 letters of a postcode to equal a city so e.g Birmingham = (b15,b16,b17) Coventry = (cv1, cv2, cv3) then when using some other code  ran the data set will add the new column to look like this

```
postcode|average download speed|    city (adds new column using variables birmingham and coventry) 

cv1 4b7           1.3             coventry 

cv2 6rb           1.5             coventry 

cv3 649           1.2             coventry  
b15 7jr           1.8             birmingham  
b16 6yt           1.5             birmingham  
b17 8rb           2.4             birmingham
```

i already have my data in a data set called wifi which i imported from a excel spreadsheet using

```
wifi = wifi <- read_excel("data/wifi.xlsx")
```

I would like to add the new column in to this data set allowing me to combine the post codes in it. I am also using tidyverse to do this.

I hope this post makes sense and has enough detail if there is any info any R pros can share to help me figure out my problem if anymore information is needed then I will be happy to try describe my problem in more detail.

Comment: Can you share some data with us? That will help. Use a command like this: dput(df[1:10, 1:5] ) You will need to replace df with the name of your dataset; the command will then print a command that replicates the first ten rows and first five columns of your data. Make adjustments as needed. Copy the output and put it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your main dataframe, you will need to use `str_remove()` from `stringr` to remove values from the space on:

```
 mydata <- mutate(mydata, postcode2 = str_remove(postcode, " .*"))
```

Then assuming your other data frame (say, called `mydata2`) looks something like:

```
postcode    city
cv1         Coventry
cv2         Coventry
cv3         Coventry
b15         Birmingham
b16         Birmingham
b1y         Birmingham
```

You can use `left_join()` from `dplyr`:

```
left_join(mydata, mydata2, by = c("postcode2" = "postcode"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use word from stringr to get the first "word" of the post code (the 3 letter prefix) and then test that with case_when.

````
Birmingham = c("b15","b16","b17") 
Coventry = c("cv1", "cv2", "cv3")
df<-df %>%
  mutate(city=case_when(
     word(postcode,1) %in% Birmingham ~ "Birmingham",
     word(postcode,1) %in% Coventry ~ "Coventry",
     TRUE ~ "other city"
  ))

```

DATA
```
df<-structure(list(postcode = c("cv1 4b7", "b16 6yt"), average_download_speed = c(1.3, 
1.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```
````

Comment: hello thanks for this very helpful, i am trying to extract multiple different string values from a  single column and assign them to a new tibble/variable.

i tried the form:                                                                                                        itemtoholddata= filter(tibble,column_name == "string1"& column_name =="string2"& column_name =="string3")

This fails. I have tried similar methods but i cannot find a method that allows multiple strings to be held in the same container

Answer (score 0):

An option with `base R` is

```
mydata$postcode2 <-  sub("\\s+.*", '', mydata$postcode)
merge(mydata, mydata2, by.x = 'postcode2', by.y = 'postcode', all.x = TRUE)
```